# Finding the distance between two points [Efficency]

Tags: java, performance, math

Instead of typing it all out, here's a picture for you to see what I want. You know what they say, *a picture is worth a thousand words*.

[image: img]

What I have is `p1`, `Θ`, and `d` and speed, `s` of the projectile.

### Speed:

From this I can deduce `p2` using the equation `p1.x * speed`, `p1.y * speed` which are the co-ordenates for `p2`. From this I can calculate the distance using the equation `|dx| + |dy|`.

### Distance

However, if I wasn't given speed, how would I be able to calculate the co-ordenates of `p2` only using `Θ`, `p1` and `d`?

---

Are there any other methods that would be the most efficent?

---

```
 public double getDistanceTraveled() {
    return Math.abs(x - oldX) + Math.abs(y - oldY); 
 }  //use Manhattan aproach as it is more efficent than Euclidean
 public double getSpeed() {
    return getDistanceTraveled() / level.TICKS_PER_SECOND; 
 }
```

is what I am using at the moment. I realized that I had the variable time, so I was able to deduce `p2` using this method:

`d = |dx| + |dy|`
`d = s / t`
`s = t(|dx| + |dy|)`

Not sure if this is that efficient though. Any suggestions to this problem, and just to repeat: I have the variables `theta`, `p1`, `d` and `t` and I have to find `p2`.

**Efficency >>> Accuracy**

Comment: You say that efficiency is more important than accuracy, but _how much_ more? It's pretty efficient to say that p2 = p1, for example, but it's unclear if that's useful to you, because it's probably not very accurate. What are the bounds on the accuracy?

Comment: @AndyTurner I have to run 30 cycles a second and not have it throttle. This includes other calculations, ofcourse

Comment: 30 cycles per second is nothing. Unless you need at least 100,000 such computations per second, so long as you are using a formula, use whichever one is more intuitive. In fact, even 100,000 would be blazing fast on most modern computers.

Comment: @nyxaria - that's a bound on the time, what are your accuracy requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `theta` is the angle between line and `y-axis`.
Then you can calculate it with the following formulas.
Let P1 be the point (p1x, p1y). and P2 be the point (p2x, p2y)

```
p2x = p1x + d * sin(theta)
p2y = p1y + d * cos(theta)
```

If you use `Math.sin(theta)`, then keep in mind that theta should be in `radians`. You can use `Math.toRadian(degree)` to get angle in `radians`.

Comment: Did you mean for `p2y` to be on both the left and right sides of the second equation?

Comment: If theta is angle between x-axis and line then yes it should be swapped. But from the image that he shown it seems to be angle between line and y-axis. @tom10

Answer (score 0):

> You know what they say, *a picture is worth a thousand words*.

[image]

Comment: I like the wit, but your math is wrong, if by a constant. p1 is not the origin.

Comment: Haha sorry I got carried away. Maths is beautiful stuff and I have yet to see past the brim!

Answer (score 0):

If you want efficiency, there's actually a much better approach than using the trig operations at all. Basically, since you already have `d`, the only thing you care about is the relative movement along `x` and `y`, which is defined by theta.

Knowing that, it's pretty trivial to just store unit vectors at whatever your required granularity is in a hashmap and multiply by `d`

After you've decided on your granularity, just pre-calculate a `HashMap` like so:

```
{0: [1, 0],
 0.01: [0.99, 0.001], etc...
}
```

Then round the incoming number, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java) question for details on making sure it matches your granularity. Then the calculation is just (in pseudo-code):

```
x = p1[0] + d * <HashMap>.getKey(angle)[0]
y = p2[1] + d * <HashMap>.getKey(angle)[1]
```

A `HashMap` lookup and a multiplication is WAY more efficient than even a single trig operation. Preliminary tests got me ~10x speedup but YMMV.

Comment: There's no need to involve hash maps where a simple array would do. If the granularity is uniform, then the array index can be derived very simply.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Ah, my mistake, I forgot that hashmaps are built on arrays in Java, I usually dev in python where the reverse is true